# Why do Arango Spark to load data requires predefined POJO strictly?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, arangodb

Usecase:

I want to load Arango collection which can infer data schema well in advance without specifying POJO class using Spark Arango. Is it possible? If yes, can you please explain how?

I have taken Datamodel from ArangoDB-GraphCourse_Beginners pdf available on Arango site. Airport is a vertice. Flight is edge. So basically Airport to Airport  is being related by flight edge.

Want to have all airports directly re
achable from LAX(Los Angeles)

Arango query:-

FOR airport IN OUTBOUND 'airport/LAX'  flights 
Return Distinct airport.

Approach:-
Arangodb spark module, i have used. As there is no direct support for AQL, so i loaded both the collection using spark arango connector.  Now while loading, i need to provide POJO class in advance.
ArangoJavaRDD airportDataset = ArangoSpark.load(javaSparkContext, AirportCollection, Airport.class)

Similarly i loaded flight collection.
Here i had to create POJO class Airport and Flight in advance.
Then,
Created spark "createOrReplaceTempView".
Now i have applied SQL query on these temp view to retrieve this result.
SQL:-
Select Distinct a.* from airportsTemp a where a.documentHandle in (Select b._to from flightTemp b where b._from = 'airport/LAX')

I am able to achieve the solution by this approach.

Issue:-
Can there be any other alternative other than POJO class for ArangoJavaRDD as for my usecase want to achieve this based on Auto scheama inferance?

Comment: Show us what you already started doing, this will help us help you.

Comment: @jgp, i have edited my question. Can you please guide?